# Differential backup in 4D database

Tags: 4d-database

I am developing an accounting application in 4D. So, I need to take differential backups everyday.

I tried to take backups by configuring in database settings but 4D only takes the full backups (not differential backup).

Do 4D database support differential backup? 
Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [backup log file](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv15R3/4D/15-R3/Configuration-of-backup-files.300-2761258.en.html#462271) that is tied into the 4D backup system.

When the backup log file is enabled a new log will be created after each backup, it will contain all of the changes until the next backup. In this way the log file file is linked to the previous backup and could be integrated back into the restored database.

To take it a step further take a look at the [`NEW LOG FILE`](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv15R3/4D/15-R3/New-log-file.301-2695850.en.html) command. This will force the creation of a new log file without doing a backup. Once done the previous log would essentially be your differential backup.

More information on managing the log file is available [here](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv15R3/4D/15-R3/Managing-the-log-file.300-2761256.en.html)

---

There is also [replication](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv15R3/4D/15-R3/Replication-via-SQL.300-2809756.en.html) and [mirroring](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv15R3/4D/15-R3/Setting-up-a-logical-mirror.300-2783382.en.html) options.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. Does that log file contains only the changes until the next backup? For eg I have set the configuration to take backups everyday.  In this case, the differential backup should reflect only the changes of that particular day. In other words, the differential backup of monday should only have the changes that take place on monday. Thank you.

Comment: If you do a backup at midnight each day and also utilize the log system then the log file will contain only the changes for each day. The log file is named with a .journal file but once the next backup runs it will become a .4bl file next to your .4bk backups and a new .journal file is created.